# elements geting out of container when hovered

Tags: html, css

I have a list of elements ordered vertically which displays certain data like an image, a title, and a description. I have a div named `.dynamicDataHoverHighlight` inside of the container with a display set to none. What I wanted to do was when I hovered on a specific container with all the data I wanted that div to have display flex but whenever I hover to display that div it works and will be visible but the other data on that parent container will get out of the container I assigned them and will get aligned to the next container under then. To better understand my problem if you hover on the first container from the list of containers you will see the IMG and the data next to it will get out of that container and move to the one below them. How can I fix this and make them stay in thier specific container? Note the hover to display div is only set to work only when hovered on the first container and the third the others won't do anything except change their background color.

```css
.shelf2 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 14%;
  left: 0%;
  width: 100%;
}

.shelf2 .dynamicShelf2Items {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 4%;
  left: 18%;
  width: 64%;
}

.shelf2 .dynamicShelf2Items .dynamicData {
  width: 100%;
  height: 13em;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #9b9999;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.shelf2 .dynamicShelf2Items .dynamicData:hover {
  background-color: #f2f0f0;
}

.shelf2 .dynamicShelf2Items .dynamicData .dynamicDataHoverHighlight {
  display: none;
  position: relative;
  top: 0%;
  left: 0%;
  width: 1.2%;
  height: 13em;
  background-color: rgb(3, 149, 3);
}

.shelf2 .dynamicShelf2Items .dynamicData:hover>.dynamicDataHoverHighlight {
  display: flex;
}

.shelf2 .dynamicShelf2Items .dynamicData .imgCon {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  position: relative;
  top: 0%;
  left: 1.5%;
  width: 30%;
  height: 100%;
}

.shelf2 .dynamicShelf2Items .dynamicData img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10%;
  left: 5%;
  width: 90%;
  height: 80%;
}

.shelf2 .dynamicShelf2Items .dynamicData .detailsCon {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  position: relative;
  top: -100%;
  left: 32%;
  width: 62%;
  height: 100%;
}

.shelf2 .dynamicShelf2Items .dynamicData .detailsCon .level1 {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  position: absolute;
  top: 10%;
  left: 0%;
  width: 100%;
  height: 15%;
}

.shelf2 .dynamicShelf2Items .dynamicData .detailsCon .level1 p {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0%;
  font-size: 1.3vw;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  margin-top: auto;
  margin-bottom: auto;
}

.shelf2 .dynamicShelf2Items .dynamicData .detailsCon .level2 {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  position: absolute;
  top: 30%;
  left: 0%;
  width: 100%;
  height: 15%;
}

.shelf2 .dynamicShelf2Items .dynamicData .detailsCon .level2 p {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0%;
  font-size: 1.1vw;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  margin-top: auto;
  margin-bottom: auto;
}

.shelf2 .dynamicShelf2Items .dynamicData .detailsCon .level3 {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 25%;
  left: 0%;
  width: 100%;
  height: 30%;
}

.shelf2 .dynamicShelf2Items .dynamicData .detailsCon .level3 p {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0%;
  font-size: 1.5vw;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  margin-top: auto;
  margin-bottom: auto;
}

.shelf2 .dynamicShelf2Items .dynamicData .detailsCon .level4 {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 10%;
  left: 0%;
  width: 100%;
  height: 15%;
}

.shelf2 .dynamicShelf2Items .dynamicData .detailsCon .level4 p {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0%;
  font-size: 1.1vw;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  margin-top: auto;
  margin-bottom: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="shelf2">
  <div class="dynamicShelf2Items">
    <div class="dynamicData">
      <div class="dynamicDataHoverHighlight">
      </div>
      <div class="imgCon">
        <img src="https://support.apple.com/library/APPLE/APPLECARE_ALLGEOS/SP790/Screen%20Shot%202019-03-19%20at%201_32_36%20PM.png" />
      </div>
      <div class="detailsCon">
        <div class="level1">
          <p>iMac 27-inches (2019) Retina 5K (4GB Graphics) in mint condition</p>
        </div>
        <div class="level2">
          <p>Apple · Mac · Grey</p>
        </div>
        <div class="level3">
          <p>US $1,999</p>
        </div>
        <div class="level4">
          <p>Used Once | Excellent Condition</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="dynamicData">
      <div class="imgCon">
        <img src="https://encrypted-tbn3.gstatic.com/shopping?q=tbn:ANd9GcSnkX1cceCzhok-fA2D5ShdGYEin2Br5zWnE_9lyssPXg_458B0ks7xhNaiVSjf9aVGhycCKlFVYxSR2wVzfGwRnso0fQwOXtKcK4fWXbw&usqp=CAE" />
      </div>
      <div class="detailsCon">
        <div class="level1">
          <p>Modern U shaped Luxury Sofa</p>
        </div>
        <div class="level2">
          <p>Tufted · Leather · Wood</p>
        </div>
        <div class="level3">
          <p>US $5,700</p>
        </div>
        <div class="level4">
          <p>Used Once | Excellent Condition</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="dynamicData">
      <div class="dynamicDataHoverHighlight">
      </div>
      <div class="imgCon">
        <img src="https://encrypted-tbn3.gstatic.com/shopping?q=tbn:ANd9GcSnkX1cceCzhok-fA2D5ShdGYEin2Br5zWnE_9lyssPXg_458B0ks7xhNaiVSjf9aVGhycCKlFVYxSR2wVzfGwRnso0fQwOXtKcK4fWXbw&usqp=CAE" />
      </div>
      <div class="detailsCon">
        <div class="level1">
          <p>Modern U shaped Luxury Sofa</p>
        </div>
        <div class="level2">
          <p>Tufted · Leather · Wood</p>
        </div>
        <div class="level3">
          <p>US $5,700</p>
        </div>
        <div class="level4">
          <p>Used Once | Excellent Condition</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="dynamicData">
      <div class="imgCon">
        <img src="https://encrypted-tbn3.gstatic.com/shopping?q=tbn:ANd9GcSnkX1cceCzhok-fA2D5ShdGYEin2Br5zWnE_9lyssPXg_458B0ks7xhNaiVSjf9aVGhycCKlFVYxSR2wVzfGwRnso0fQwOXtKcK4fWXbw&usqp=CAE" />
      </div>
      <div class="detailsCon">
        <div class="level1">
          <p>Modern U shaped Luxury Sofa</p>
        </div>
        <div class="level2">
          <p>Tufted · Leather · Wood</p>
        </div>
        <div class="level3">
          <p>US $5,700</p>
        </div>
        <div class="level4">
          <p>Used Once | Excellent Condition</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Why are you using hardcoded position values when you can just use flexbox aligning properties?

Comment: hardcoding it usually gives me more control over my elements positioning but I'm open to flexbox alignment too. @m4n0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To fix this set the `position to absolute of dynamicDataHoverHighlight` div.

```css
.shelf2 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 14%;
  left: 0%;
  width: 100%;
}

.shelf2 .dynamicShelf2Items {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 4%;
  left: 18%;
  width: 64%;
}

.shelf2 .dynamicShelf2Items .dynamicData {
  width: 100%;
  height: 13em;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #9b9999;
  cursor: pointer;
  position:relative;
}

.shelf2 .dynamicShelf2Items .dynamicData:hover {
  background-color: #f2f0f0;
}

.shelf2 .dynamicShelf2Items .dynamicData .dynamicDataHoverHighlight {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0%;
  left: 0%;
  width: 1.2%;
  height: 13em;
  background-color: rgb(3, 149, 3);
}

.shelf2 .dynamicShelf2Items .dynamicData:hover>.dynamicDataHoverHighlight {
  display: flex;
}

.shelf2 .dynamicShelf2Items .dynamicData .imgCon {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  position: relative;
  top: 0%;
  left: 1.5%;
  width: 30%;
  height: 100%;
}

.shelf2 .dynamicShelf2Items .dynamicData img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10%;
  left: 5%;
  width: 90%;
  height: 80%;
}

.shelf2 .dynamicShelf2Items .dynamicData .detailsCon {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  position: relative;
  top: -100%;
  left: 32%;
  width: 62%;
  height: 100%;
}

.shelf2 .dynamicShelf2Items .dynamicData .detailsCon .level1 {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  position: absolute;
  top: 10%;
  left: 0%;
  width: 100%;
  height: 15%;
}

.shelf2 .dynamicShelf2Items .dynamicData .detailsCon .level1 p {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0%;
  font-size: 1.3vw;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  margin-top: auto;
  margin-bottom: auto;
}

.shelf2 .dynamicShelf2Items .dynamicData .detailsCon .level2 {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  position: absolute;
  top: 30%;
  left: 0%;
  width: 100%;
  height: 15%;
}

.shelf2 .dynamicShelf2Items .dynamicData .detailsCon .level2 p {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0%;
  font-size: 1.1vw;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  margin-top: auto;
  margin-bottom: auto;
}

.shelf2 .dynamicShelf2Items .dynamicData .detailsCon .level3 {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 25%;
  left: 0%;
  width: 100%;
  height: 30%;
}

.shelf2 .dynamicShelf2Items .dynamicData .detailsCon .level3 p {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0%;
  font-size: 1.5vw;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  margin-top: auto;
  margin-bottom: auto;
}

.shelf2 .dynamicShelf2Items .dynamicData .detailsCon .level4 {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 10%;
  left: 0%;
  width: 100%;
  height: 15%;
}

.shelf2 .dynamicShelf2Items .dynamicData .detailsCon .level4 p {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0%;
  font-size: 1.1vw;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  margin-top: auto;
  margin-bottom: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="shelf2">
  <div class="dynamicShelf2Items">
    <div class="dynamicData">
      <div class="dynamicDataHoverHighlight">
      </div>
      <div class="imgCon">
        <img src="https://support.apple.com/library/APPLE/APPLECARE_ALLGEOS/SP790/Screen%20Shot%202019-03-19%20at%201_32_36%20PM.png" />
      </div>
      <div class="detailsCon">
        <div class="level1">
          <p>iMac 27-inches (2019) Retina 5K (4GB Graphics) in mint condition</p>
        </div>
        <div class="level2">
          <p>Apple · Mac · Grey</p>
        </div>
        <div class="level3">
          <p>US $1,999</p>
        </div>
        <div class="level4">
          <p>Used Once | Excellent Condition</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="dynamicData">
      <div class="imgCon">
        <img src="https://encrypted-tbn3.gstatic.com/shopping?q=tbn:ANd9GcSnkX1cceCzhok-fA2D5ShdGYEin2Br5zWnE_9lyssPXg_458B0ks7xhNaiVSjf9aVGhycCKlFVYxSR2wVzfGwRnso0fQwOXtKcK4fWXbw&usqp=CAE" />
      </div>
      <div class="detailsCon">
        <div class="level1">
          <p>Modern U shaped Luxury Sofa</p>
        </div>
        <div class="level2">
          <p>Tufted · Leather · Wood</p>
        </div>
        <div class="level3">
          <p>US $5,700</p>
        </div>
        <div class="level4">
          <p>Used Once | Excellent Condition</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="dynamicData">
      <div class="dynamicDataHoverHighlight">
      </div>
      <div class="imgCon">
        <img src="https://encrypted-tbn3.gstatic.com/shopping?q=tbn:ANd9GcSnkX1cceCzhok-fA2D5ShdGYEin2Br5zWnE_9lyssPXg_458B0ks7xhNaiVSjf9aVGhycCKlFVYxSR2wVzfGwRnso0fQwOXtKcK4fWXbw&usqp=CAE" />
      </div>
      <div class="detailsCon">
        <div class="level1">
          <p>Modern U shaped Luxury Sofa</p>
        </div>
        <div class="level2">
          <p>Tufted · Leather · Wood</p>
        </div>
        <div class="level3">
          <p>US $5,700</p>
        </div>
        <div class="level4">
          <p>Used Once | Excellent Condition</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="dynamicData">
      <div class="imgCon">
        <img src="https://encrypted-tbn3.gstatic.com/shopping?q=tbn:ANd9GcSnkX1cceCzhok-fA2D5ShdGYEin2Br5zWnE_9lyssPXg_458B0ks7xhNaiVSjf9aVGhycCKlFVYxSR2wVzfGwRnso0fQwOXtKcK4fWXbw&usqp=CAE" />
      </div>
      <div class="detailsCon">
        <div class="level1">
          <p>Modern U shaped Luxury Sofa</p>
        </div>
        <div class="level2">
          <p>Tufted · Leather · Wood</p>
        </div>
        <div class="level3">
          <p>US $5,700</p>
        </div>
        <div class="level4">
          <p>Used Once | Excellent Condition</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: no this is not right if you hover on the third container the ```dynamicDataHoverHighlight``` will be visible on the first container

Comment: @seriously It is right now. I have fixed the bug now.

Comment: Thanks! What exactly was the bug can you please add an explanation above.

Comment: While hovering on third div it show `dynamicDataHoverHighlight` on first div because the position of `dynamicData` div was not set relative.